# Reversing a subsequence of numbers

Tags: c++, reverse

I am trying to fill a new array on type int from reversing a subsequence in the the original array using the reverse function. However I'm just getting the same sequence of numbers back. Could somebody please point out my error please? Thank you in advance.

```
double swap4()
{
    int i = rand()%(n-1);     //choose radom sub seq. start point.
    int k = rand()%(n-i);      //choose radom sub seq. end point.
    int *p;
    int *q;
    p = &Path[i];
    q = &Path[k];
    reverse(p,q);               //reverse the sequence.

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        neworder[j] = Path[j];          //create a new array to store the new sequnece.
    }

    reverse(p,q);                           //reverse again to regain the origional.

    cout<<" the reversed path is "<< endl;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)                        //print out new sequence.
    {
        cout << neworder[i]<< " ";
    }

    cout<< neworder[0] <<")"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

k should be initialized as -

```
int k = i + rand()%(n-i);
```

Comment: My god. Thanks very much. My head is mush.    -_-